# Python3 - Replace Values in JSON Object

Tags: python, json, api

I'm running an API query that returns three key value pairs:

```
{'enabled': True, 'recording': False, 'autoDeletion': False}
```

I need to replace the values with `1` and `0` respectively, to obtain:

```
{'enabled': 1, 'recording': 0, 'autoDeletion': 0}
```

I've tried using json.dumps.replace, but I just get a list of errors from the JSON encoder module, culminating in "TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable", which is why it's commented out in the code.

Is there a simple way to achieve this seemingly trivial substitution please?

Here's the code

```py
#Make API request
api_response = requests.request("GET", server + query_endpoint, headers=query_headers, data=query_payload)

#api_test = json.dumps(api_response).replace('"true"','"1"')

print(api_response.json())
```

And the output looks like this:

```
{'enabled': True, 'recording': False, 'autoDeletion': False}
```

Comment: >>> d = {'enabled': True, 'recording': False, 'autoDeletion': False}
>>> {k: 1 if v else 0 for k, v in d.items()}
{'enabled': 1, 'recording': 0, 'autoDeletion': 0}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `.json()` return a `dict`, then do like this,

```py
data = api_response.json()
for k,v in data.items():
    data[k] = int(v)
print(data)
```

Output:

```py
{'enabled': 1, 'recording': 0, 'autoDeletion': 0}
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **[dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)** and just cast each value to an int:

```
api_response_json = {k: int(v) for k, v in api_response.json().items()}
print(api_response_json)
```

**Output:**

```
{'enabled': 1, 'recording': 0, 'autoDeletion': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks gents. That seems to have done it!